# Some resources are not getting created by cloudformation

Tags: json, load-balancing, autoscaling, aws-opsworks, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a cloudformation template that creates a stack, a layer, an application, 2 instances for the layer and a load balancer and an auto scaling group. Here is the FULL template:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "AWS CloudFormation Template : Building the opsworks stack",


  "Mappings": {

    "Region2Principal": {

      "us-east-1": {
        "EC2Principal": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "OpsWorksPrincipal": "opsworks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "us-west-2": {
        "EC2Principal": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "OpsWorksPrincipal": "opsworks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "us-west-1": {
        "EC2Principal": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "OpsWorksPrincipal": "opsworks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "eu-west-1": {
        "EC2Principal": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "OpsWorksPrincipal": "opsworks.amazonaws.com"
      }
    },

    "RegionMap" : {
      "us-east-1" : { "64" : "ami-5ac2cd4d" },
      "us-west-1" : { "64" : "ami-7790c617" },
      "eu-west-1" : { "64" : "ami-b9b394ca" },
      "us-west-2" : { "64" : "ami-30e65350" }
    }

  },

  "Parameters": {

    "OpsWorksStackColor": {
      "Description": "RGB Color to use for OpsWorks Stack",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "rgb(38, 146, 168)"
    },

    "Region" : {
      "Type":"String",
      "Description": "Region location of the template resources",
      "Default": "eu-west-1",
      "AllowedValues" : [ "us-east-1", "us-west-1", "us-west-2", "eu-west-1" ]
    },

    "EnvironnementParam" : {
      "Type" : "String",
      "Description" : "Environnement variable for the stack benchmark layer",
      "Default" : "dev"
    },

    "SecurityGroupIds": {
      "Description": "Security groups that can be used to access the EC2 instances, do not select more than 5 SG",
      "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be list of EC2 security group ids"
    },

    "VpcId": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
      "Description": "VPC associated with the provided subnets",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be an existing VPC ID"
    },

    "SubnetId": {
      "Type": "String",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be an existing subnet ID"
    },

    "InstanceType" : {
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default" : "t2.medium",
      "AllowedValues" : ["t2.micro","t2.medium", "m1.small", "m1.large","m4.large","m4.xlarge","m4.2xlarge","m4.4xlarge","m4.10xlarge","m4.16xlarge","c4.large" , "c4.xlarge" ,"c4.2xlarge" , "c4.4xlarge","c4.8xlarge" , "c3.large" , "c3.xlarge", "c3.2xlarge", "c3.4xlarge" ,"c3.8xlarge"],
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type"
    },

    "SSLCertificateIdForELB": {
      "Description" : "Choose the ID of an existing certificate from AWS Certificate Manager to configure the ELB Listeners. If no certificate is available, leave an empty string. The certificate will be created by CloudFormation",
      "Type" : "String"
    },
    "KeyPairName": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair"
    },

    "Instance1AZ": {
      "Description": "Select the Availablity zone of the instance silo import 1, must be the same AZ as the volume of the instance, insert 0,1 or 2",
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default": "0"
    },

    "Instance2AZ": {
      "Description": "Select the Availablity zone of the instance silo import 2, must be the same AZ as the volume of the instance, insert 0,1 or 2",
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default": "0"
    }

  },

  "Conditions" : {
    "CreateCertificateSSL": { "Fn::Equals" :[ {"Ref" : "SSLCertificateIdForELB" }, ""] }
  },

  "Resources": {

    "OpsWorksInstanceRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version" : "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [ {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service" : [ {"Fn::FindInMap": [ "Region2Principal", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },"EC2Principal" ] } ] },
            "Action"  : [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
          }]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies":
        [{
          "PolicyName": {"Fn::Join" : ["",[{"Ref" : "AWS::StackName"},"Instance"] ] },
          "PolicyDocument": {
            "Statement": [{
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "*",
              "Resource": "*"
            }]
          }
        }]
      }
    },

    "OpsWorksServiceRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version" : "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [ {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": [ { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "Region2Principal",{ "Ref": "AWS::Region" },"OpsWorksPrincipal" ] } ] },
            "Action" : [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
          }]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [ {
          "PolicyName": "OpsworksService",
          "PolicyDocument": {
            "Version" : "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [ {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "*",
              "Resource": "*"
            }]
          }
        }]
      }
    },

    "myStack": {
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Stack",
      "Properties": {
        "AgentVersion" : "LATEST",
        "Name": { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
        "Attributes": { "Color": { "Ref": "OpsWorksStackColor" } },
        "ChefConfiguration": { "BerkshelfVersion" : "3.2.0", "ManageBerkshelf" : true },
        "ConfigurationManager": { "Name": "Chef", "Version": "11.10" },
        "CustomCookbooksSource": {
          "Type": "git",
          "Url": "git://github.com/amazonwebservices/opsworks-example-cookbooks.git"
        },
        "DefaultInstanceProfileArn": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "InstanceProfile","Arn" ] },
        "DefaultOs": "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS",
        "DefaultRootDeviceType": "ebs",
        "DefaultSshKeyName": { "Ref": "KeyPairName" },
        "DefaultSubnetId" : {"Ref" : "SubnetId" },
        "ServiceRoleArn": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["OpsWorksServiceRole", "Arn"] },
        "UseCustomCookbooks": true,
        "UseOpsworksSecurityGroups" : true,
        "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" }
      }
    },

    "InstanceProfile": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
      "Properties": {
        "Path": "/",
        "Roles": [ { "Ref": "OpsWorksInstanceRole" } ]
      }
    },

    "myLayer": {
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Layer",
      "DependsOn" : "OpsWorksServiceRole",
      "Properties": {
        "AutoAssignElasticIps" : false,
        "AutoAssignPublicIps" : true,
        "CustomSecurityGroupIds" : { "Ref" : "SecurityGroupIds" },
        "EnableAutoHealing" : true,
        "InstallUpdatesOnBoot": false,
        "LifecycleEventConfiguration": {
          "ShutdownEventConfiguration": {
            "DelayUntilElbConnectionsDrained": false,
            "ExecutionTimeout": 120 }
          },
          "Name": "layer",
          "Shortname" : "layer",
          "StackId": { "Ref": "myStack" },
          "Type": "custom",
          "UseEbsOptimizedInstances": false,
          "VolumeConfigurations": [ {
            "Iops": 10000,
            "MountPoint": "/mountp",
            "NumberOfDisks": 1,
            "Size": 20,
            "VolumeType": "gp2"
          }]
      }
    },

    "ELBSecurityGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription" : "api-elb",
        "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "VpcId" },
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
          {
            "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
            "FromPort" : "80",
            "ToPort" : "80",
            "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
          }],
          "SecurityGroupEgress" : [{
            "IpProtocol" : "-1",
            "FromPort" : "-1",
            "ToPort" : "-1",
            "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
          }]
      }
    },

    "ELB": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties": {
        "ConnectionDrainingPolicy" : {
          "Enabled" : true,
          "Timeout" : 300
        },
        "ConnectionSettings" : {
          "IdleTimeout" : 60
        },
        "CrossZone" : true,
        "HealthCheck" : {
          "HealthyThreshold" : "3",
          "Interval" : "30",
          "Target" : "HTTP:80/ping",
          "Timeout" : "5",
          "UnhealthyThreshold" : "2"
        },
        "Instances" : [ {"Ref" : "Instance1" }, {"Ref" : "Instance2"}],
        "LoadBalancerName" : "api-ELB",
        "Listeners" : [
          {
            "InstancePort" : "443",
            "InstanceProtocol" : "HTTPS",
            "LoadBalancerPort" : "443",
            "Protocol" : "HTTPS"
          },
          {
            "InstancePort" : "80",
            "InstanceProtocol" : "HTTP",
            "LoadBalancerPort" : "80",
            "Protocol" : "HTTP",
            "PolicyNames" :[ "ELBSecurityPolicy-2015-05" ],
            "SSLCertificateId" : {"Fn::If": ["CreateCertificateSSL", {"Ref" : "ELBCertificate" }, { "Ref" : "SSLCertificateIdForELB" } ] }
          }
        ],
        "Scheme" : "internal",
        "SecurityGroups" : { "Ref" : "ELBSecurityGroup" },
        "Subnets" : [ {"Ref" : "SubnetId" } ]
      }
    },

    "ELBAttachment" :{
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::ElasticLoadBalancerAttachment",
      "Properties": {
        "ElasticLoadBalancerName" : {"Ref" : "ELB" },
        "LayerId" : { "Ref" : "myLayer"}
      }
    },

    "LaunchConfig" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Properties" : {
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress" : true,
        "BlockDeviceMappings" : [{
          "DeviceName" : "/dev/sdi",
          "Ebs":{
            "VolumeType" : "gp2",
            "Iops" : "10000",
            "DeleteOnTermination" : "false",
            "VolumeSize" : "20"
          }
        }],
        "EbsOptimized" : false,
        "IamInstanceProfile" : { "Fn::GetAtt" :[ "InstanceProfile", "Arn" ] },
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "64"]},
        "InstanceType" : {"Ref" : "InstanceType" },
        "SecurityGroups" : [{ "Ref" : "ELBSecurityGroup" }]
      }
    },

    "ASG" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "AvailabilityZones" : { "Fn::GetAZs" : { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" } },
        "Cooldown" : "1",
        "HealthCheckGracePeriod" : 3,
        "HealthCheckType" : "ELB",
        "LaunchConfigurationName" : {"Ref" : "LaunchConfig" },
        "LoadBalancerNames" : [{ "Ref" : "ELB" }],
        "MaxSize" : "5",
        "MetricsCollection" : [ { "Granularity" : "5Minute" } ],
        "MinSize" : "2",
        "Tags" : [
          {
            "PropagateAtLaunch": true,
            "Value": {"Ref" : "EnvironnementParam" },
            "Key": "environment"
          },
          {
            "PropagateAtLaunch": true,
            "Value": {"Ref" : "myLayer" },
            "Key": "my layer"
          }],
        "VPCZoneIdentifier" : [ {"Ref" : "VpcId" } ]
      }
    },

    "ELBCertificate" :{
      "Type" : "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate",
      "Condition" : "CreateCertificateSSL",
      "Properties" : {
        "DomainName" : "example.com",
        "SubjectAlternativeNames" : [ "example.net" ]
      }
    },

    "Instance1": {
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "Hostname": "silo-import1",
        "AvailabilityZone" : { "Fn::Select" : [ {"Ref" : "Instance1AZ"}, { "Fn::GetAZs" : {"Ref" : "Region"} } ] },
        "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
        "StackId": {"Ref": "myStack"},
        "LayerIds": [{"Ref": "myLayer"}],
        "InstanceType": {"Ref" : "InstanceType"}
      }
    },

    "Instance2": {
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "Hostname": "silo-import2",
        "AvailabilityZone" : { "Fn::Select" : [ {"Ref" : "Instance2AZ"}, { "Fn::GetAZs" : {"Ref" : "Region"} } ] },
        "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
        "StackId": {"Ref": "myStack"},
        "LayerIds": [{"Ref": "myLayer"}],
        "InstanceType": {"Ref" : "InstanceType"}
    }
  },

    "AdminApiApp": {
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::App",
      "Properties": {
        "AppSource" : {
          "Type" : "git",
          "Url" : "git://github.com:fap/adminphp.git",
          "Revision" : "develop"
        },
        "Name" : "admin",
        "Shortname" : "admin",
        "StackId" : {"Ref": "myStack"},
        "Type" : "php"
      }
    }

  }

}
```

My problem is I don't know why the autoscaling group does not get created nor the elastic load balancer. When I test the template, all the resources are created except these. Any explaination ? I'm ready to try all your suggestions.
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot above, it looks like your stack's state is still in `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`. One of your resources (probably your [`AWS::OpsWorks::Instance`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opsworks-instance.html)?) did not get created correctly. To troubleshoot, you can try [logging into the instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/troubleshoot-debug-login.html), checking the OpsWorks [Chef Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/troubleshoot-debug-log.html), or looking at output logs on the instance (`/var/log/cfn-init.log` and `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`) to find the underlying cause/error.

More generally, refer to the AWS Knowledge Center article, [How do I troubleshoot an AWS CloudFormation stack that is stuck with a status of `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` or `UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS`?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-create-in-progress/):

> #### Short Description
>
> This condition typically occurs when there are problems with the resource that is being created or updated, causing the stack to eventually fail. If there is no timeout parameter specified for the stack, it will take longer for the stack to reach the `CREATE_FAILED` or `UPDATE_FAILED` state.
>
> #### Resolution
>
> - If possible, check the exact resource that CloudFormation is stuck creating. Auto Scaling often provides clear error messages to describe events that prevent instances from launching.
> - Ensure that you are not exceeding the AWS limits for the resources that you want to create. For example, if the CloudFormation template specifies two EC2 instances but your instance count is currently at 19 with an upper limit of 20, the stack creation fails.

See also [Monitoring the Progress of a Stack Update](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-monitor-stack.html) section of the documentation.